# LLVM IR codegen segfaults during exit only when method declarations have parameters

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, bison, flex-lexer, llvm-c++-api

### **Explanation**

I am creating a compiler for a C-like language using yacc/bison, flex, and the LLVM toolchain (LLVM 12) using the LLVM C++ API.
I have been developing and testing on Ubuntu version 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) and macOS 11.6 Big Sur.
Currently, the issue is the program segfaulting when exiting the program when a method declaration has method parameters such as simply:

```
func test(x int) void {}
```

The LLVM IR will be printed properly as

```
; ModuleID = 'Test'
source_filename = "Test"

define void @test(i32 %x) {
entry:
  %x1 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %x, i32* %x1, align 4
  ret void
}
```

And will segfault immediately after.

A method declaration like

```
func test() int {
    var x int;
    x = 5;
    return (x);
}
```

Will not segfault.

GDB reports that the segfault occurs during `llvm::LLVMContextImpl::~LLVMContextImpl()`. Valgrind reports `~LLVMContextImpl()` doing an invalid read of size 8.

Edit: Valgrind output relating to invalid read

```
==10254== Invalid read of size 8
==10254==    at 0x5553C30: llvm::LLVMContextImpl::~LLVMContextImpl() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1)
==10254==    by 0x5552130: llvm::LLVMContext::~LLVMContext() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1)
==10254==    by 0xA44AA26: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:108)
==10254==    by 0xA44ABDF: exit (exit.c:139)
==10254==    by 0xA4280B9: (below main) (libc-start.c:342)
==10254==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==10254== 
==10254== 
==10254== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==10254==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==10254==    at 0x5553C30: llvm::LLVMContextImpl::~LLVMContextImpl() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1)
==10254==    by 0x5552130: llvm::LLVMContext::~LLVMContext() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1)
==10254==    by 0xA44AA26: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:108)
==10254==    by 0xA44ABDF: exit (exit.c:139)
==10254==    by 0xA4280B9: (below main) (libc-start.c:342)
==10254==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==10254==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==10254==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==10254==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==10254==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

I'm hoping that by asking here I can get some kind of hint for how to work towards solving this issue. I've been stuck on this for days.

### **Source Code Fragments**

The sections of my code relating to method declarations and method parameters are as follow, I apologize for the length:

Bison grammar rule for program

```
program: extern_list decafpackage
    { 
        ProgramAST *prog = new ProgramAST((decafStmtList*)$1, (PackageAST*)$2); 
        if (printAST) {
            cout << getString(prog) << endl;
        }
        prog->Codegen();
        delete prog;
    }
    ;
```

Bison grammar rule for method declaration

```
method_decl: T_FUNC T_ID T_LPAREN params T_RPAREN method_type method_block 
    {
        $$ = new Method(*$2, $6->str(), $4, $7);
        delete $2; 
        delete $6;
    }
```

Bison grammar rule for method parameter

```
param: T_ID type { $$ = new VarDef(*$1, $2->str()); delete $1; delete $2; }
    ;
```

C++ Method::Codegen() handling of parameters

```
llvm::Function *func = llvm::Function::Create(
            llvm::FunctionType::get(returnTy, args, false),
            llvm::Function::ExternalLinkage,
            name,
            TheModule
        );

llvm::BasicBlock *BB = llvm::BasicBlock::Create(TheContext, "entry", func);
Builder.SetInsertPoint(BB);

. . .

for (auto &Arg : func->args()) {
            llvm::AllocaInst* Alloca = CreateEntryBlockAlloca(func, Arg.getName().str());
            Builder.CreateStore(&Arg, Alloca);
            sTStack->enter_symtbl(Arg.getName().str(), Alloca);
        }
```

C++ VarDef::Codegen()

```
llvm::Value *Codegen() {
        llvm::Type* ty = getLLVMType(type);
        llvm::AllocaInst* V = Builder.CreateAlloca(ty, 0, name);
        V->setName(name);
        sTStack->enter_symtbl(name, V);
        return V;
        return nullptr;
    }
```

Bison main

```
int main() {
  // Setup
  llvm::LLVMContext &Context = TheContext;
  TheModule = new llvm::Module("Test", Context);
  FPM = std::make_unique<llvm::legacy::FunctionPassManager>(TheModule);
  FPM->add(llvm::createPromoteMemoryToRegisterPass());
  FPM->add(llvm::createInstructionCombiningPass());
  FPM->add(llvm::createReassociatePass());
  FPM->add(llvm::createGVNPass());
  FPM->add(llvm::createCFGSimplificationPass());
  FPM->doInitialization();

  int retval = yyparse();

  TheModule->print(llvm::errs(), nullptr);
  return(retval >= 1 ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: When using valgrind (or better, AddressSanitizer) and it says you're doing an invalid read, it is important to look at *where* that invalid read is. Is it off the end of a valid  object? Is it part of a recently-freed object? If you pass the correct options, it will track where the nearby object was allocated/deallocated.

Comment: @o11c I've added the output from Valgrind relating to the invalid read. I'll try digging around with Valgrind/GDB/debuggers some more to see if I can find out where the invalid read is happening.

Comment: This is "probably" not the source of the crash (though it might be), but you never delete your module.

Comment: @o11c: The address being read is a null pointer.

Comment: If you can either step into the destructor `llvm::LLVMContextImpl::~LLVMContextImpl()` (with a version of the library that has debug symbols), or disassemble it and inspect registers/memory at the point of the crash, you may be able to find out where it got the null pointer that it's dereferencing.  Place a write watchpoint on that pointer object and run the program again.  You may then be able to see where it got nulled out, and investigate whether or not that should have happened.

Comment: @Frank I don't explicitly delete TheModule, maybe the issue is its default destructor being called during exit.

Comment: @NateEldredge Great idea, I'll try your suggestions and update my question if I find anything.

Comment: @TrevorBonas The llvm context, which is a global variable and thus is destroyed after `main()` goes out of scope cleans up after itself, which includes deleting leftover modules.  If the module depends on something (like a string) that is scoped to `main()`, that will cause trouble. What puzzles me is that the tutorial you appear to have used as a base correctly uses `std::unique_ptr<>` everywhere, including for managing the Module, and that prevents such bugs. I don't understand why you would intentionally replace it with a naked `new`.

Comment: @Frank I am using multiple tutorials to help write this compiler, one of them declares  `TheModule` as a `static llvm::Module*` and uses a `new` to create it in `main()` as I have. I changed `TheModule` to a `std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module>` but this had no effect. My next step is recompiling LLVM with debug features so that I can step through `~LLVMContextImpl()`.

Comment: I'm suspicious of `VarDef(*$1, $2->str()); delete $1;` but of course it's possible that the `VarDef` constructor copies the string it's passed as the first argument. There's far too little code in your question to really attempt to answer.

Comment: @rici Sorry, my source code is around two thousand lines long. `VarDef` has a private `name` variable and the constructor just does `this->name = name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

The problem was in lines of code not included. `llvm::Function::Create` requires an `llvm::FunctionType` which can be provided by filling a vector with `llvm::Type*` objects. I wrote a function to do this:

```cpp
void getLLVMTypes(vector<llvm::Type*>* v) {
    for (auto* i : stmts) {
        llvm::Type* type = getLLVMType(i->getType());
        ((llvm::Value*)(type))->setName(i->getName()); // Problem
        v->push_back(type);
    }
}
```

The issue was casting each `llvm::Type*` object to `llvm::Value*` and using `llvm::Value::setName` to set its name. I did this to counter a problem I had earlier with parameter names not being set. I'm not entirely sure what the issue was, I had trouble compiling LLVM from source with debug flags, but it's a gnarly looking line of code and removing it, along with using an alternative way to preserve method parameter names, solved the issue.